# Relative Numbers sidepanel with wrapped lines

Tags: line-numbers, wrapping

I love the relative numbers side-column in vim but when I have wrapped lines it becomes inaccurate (or less usable since I can't use that number directly in a `j/k` command). I have `nnoremap j gj` in my vimrc which is why I have that discrepancy but is there a way for the `:rnu` command to reflect the lines a wrapped number takes?

Thanks

*If that made no sense, I'd like wrapped line 4 and 6 to have numbers all the way down not not skipping visible lines.

[image]

Comment: This is not possible without some serious hackery, and also not really desirable, the definition of a "line" is 0 or more characters ended by a newline, if you change that definition, you change *a lot* in Vim. For example, what would you expect `,3s/A/B/` to do? Use the next 3 lines? Or the next 3 "wrapped lines"? I understand why you're asking this, but I think your proposed 'solution' will cause you more problems than you will solve.

Comment: Perhaps consider (automatically) hardwrapping your lines: if you edit in markdown, or LaTeX, there's no difference; and you can also `J`oin lines at any time. You get all the benefits, with none of the disadvantages.

Comment: Thanks for both comments. I see your point carpetsmoker although I wish it were different. True, vanlaser but other languages aren't so kind and oftentimes I only want to sometimes see the end of the line (ie huge JavaScript arrays)

Comment: At the moment of writing vim unfortunately lacks the feature. But it is definitely a worthy one, and FWIW Emacs have had it since the very moment they merged hybrid line numbers *(through `visual` value of `display-line-numbers`)*. So I reported it, you can subscribe, or vote for implementation *(or maybe even implement it ;))* https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/3250

Answer (score 4):

You state that your current workflow is "inaccurate" and "less usable". You can solve the former (but arguably not the latter) by replacing your current `j` mapping with:

```
nnoremap <expr> j v:count == 0 ? 'gj' : "\<Esc>".v:count.'j'
```

With this mapping, you can still use a plain <kbd>j</kbd> to move down one screen line at a time, but if you use a count, then you will move down to the line indicated by the corresponding `'relativenumber'` marker. Accurate! :)

However, because there are no markers on the later screen lines of single wrapped lines, you still cannot use `Nj` to jump to those lines. Still less usable :(.

## How it works

This is an expression mapping, which maps to different commands depending on the current count.

If there is no count, it simply performs a `gj`. If there `is` a count it first clears the existing count with <kbd>Esc</kbd>, and then performs a regular `j` using the value of that count.

See:

- `:help :map-expr`
- `:help v:count`
- `:help expr1`

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try that now, this is a very clever solution

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible without some serious hackery. In fact, I can't really think of a hack short of modifying the Vim source code.

I also doubt that you *really* want this. The definition of a "line" is 0 or more characters ended by a newline, if you change that definition, you change a lot in Vim. For example, what would you expect a command like `:s/A/B/` to do? Change everything on the "real" line? Or only the "virtual" line? Or what about `:,3s/A/B/`? Use the next 3 lines? Or the next 3 "virtual" lines?

I understand why you're asking this, but I think your proposed 'solution' will cause you more problems than you will solve.

Comment: I have been using the "proposed solution" you're rejecting for at least a year in Emacs, and given I found this post for trying to make it work for gvim *(which I'm using for quick browsing and as an external editor)*, I dare you it caused me no trouble.